# Count items with condition in DataFrame Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
index column1 column2 column3
1          30      55      62
2          69      20      40
3          23      62      23
...
```

May I know how to count the number of values which are `> 50` for all elements in the above table?

I'm trying below method:

```
count = 0
for column in df.items():
    count += df[df[column] > 50][column].count()
```

Is this a proper way to do it? Or any other more effective suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can just check all the values at once and then `sum()` them since True evaluates to 1 and False to 0:

```
df.gt(50).sum().sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

`(df > 54).values.sum()` will do what you're looking for here is the total code to get the results:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
>>> df
    A   B
0  68  92
1  47  53
2   5  35
3  75  82
4  51  89
>>> (df > 54).values.sum()
5
>>>
```

Basically what I'm doing is creating a mask of true false values of the entire data frame based on the condition in this case `> 54` and then just rolling up the data frame because true/false is equal to 1/0 when added.